# autoreconf fails with "possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0"

Tags: c, autoconf, automake, slurm, autoreconf

While modifying [this source code](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm) I got this error from `autoreconf`:

```
$ autoreconf
configure.ac:240: warning: macro 'AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0' not found in library
configure.ac:246: warning: macro 'AM_PATH_GTK_2_0' not found in library
configure.ac:240: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:246: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_GTK_2_0
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

The line in `configure.ac` is:

```
AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0([2.7.1], [ac_glib_test="yes"], [ac_glib_test="no"], [gthread])
```

Is this a problem with the version of the autoconf/automake tool I'm using, or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to have glib development package installed

Comment: It happened to me when I used an older version of autoconf. But your answer worked well!

Comment: On CentOS 7, install package `glib2-devel` and `gtk2-devel`.

Comment: `sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev`

Answer (score 5):

I did following on Centos8:

```
sudo find /usr /opt -name "*.m4" -exec grep -H AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0 {} \;
```

to findout the directory containing glib-2.0.m4

```
/usr/share/aclocal/glib-2.0.m4:dnl AM_PATH_GLIB_2_0([MINIMUM-VERSION, [ACTION-IF-FOUND [, ACTION-IF-NOT-FOUND [, MODULES]]]])
```

Issuing

```
export ACLOCAL_PATH=/usr/share/aclocal
```

solved the problem